# setObjectId is not working

Tags: parse-platform

I wonder if is possible to assign an id when an item is created with parse:

```
ParseObject parseWord = new ParseObject(DataBaseHelper.TABLE_WORD);
            parseWord.setObjectId(idRow);
            parseWord.put(Word.NAME, word.getName());
            parseWord.put(Word.TYPE, word.getType());
            parseWord.put(Word.TRANSLATE, word.getTranslate());
            parseWord.put(Word.EXAMPLE, word.getExample());
            parseWord.put(Word.NOTE, word.getNote());
            parseWord.put(Word.SYNC_AT, today);
            parseWord.saveInBackground();
```

This code is not working, it doesnt save the item in the server. If I delete the setObjectId(idRow); it works. What am I doing wrong?.

Is there anyway to know when the saveInBackground is done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the ParseObject.setObjectID() API doc:

> Setter for the object id. In general you do not need to use this.
>   However, in some cases this can be convenient. For example, if you are
>   serializing a ParseObject yourself and wish to recreate it, you can
>   use this to recreate the ParseObject exactly.

Also from the API doc:

> An object id is assigned as soon as an object is saved to the server.

A reason, as the quote suggests, you might need to set the object ID is if you, wish to do something like save the fields of a parse object to a file.  If you wanted to take the fields from your file and recreate a parse object, THEN you'd need to set it, as that's not done for you if you're not saving it to the server and just using an instance of the object for purposes internal to your application.

Comment: Likely trying to set your own is futile, based on their internal schema definition.  I can't be sure of the exact error, but they clearly don't support it.  But don't worry, there's likely no reason for you to concern yourself with the exact ID they're choosing, because it's definitely going to be unique.

Comment: Well I guess the only solution is to create another column with the id generated by my app. But thanks a lot for the response :).

Comment: Yeah, bad idea to try to synchronize IDs anyway.  Something else can add an ID that your app already has, and then you'd need to resync it.. and vice versa too.  It's possible that your app is the only thing adding/removing IDs, so you won't have to worry about this, but parse.com clearly doesn't intend to trust you on that, nor to bother implementing the functionality they would need in order to trust you :)  Better to let databases enforce uniqueness of IDs they have direct control over.